# PHPUnit - Why would PHPUnit appear to be running in strict mode?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

The question: Why would PHPUnit appear to be running in strict mode?

The issue:

> PHPUnit 4.3.1 by Sebastian Bergmann.
>
> Configuration read from /full/path/to/configuration.xml
>
> R
>
> Time: 2.65 seconds, Memory: 11.50Mb
>
> OK, but incomplete, skipped, or risky tests! Tests: 1, Assertions: 1,
>   Risky: 1.           Done.

Also:

> Risky Test: Test code or tested code did not (only) close its own
>   output buffers

My PHP Version is 5.4.

As stated in the documentation (https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/strict-mode.html) this only appears to apply to PHPUnits' strict mode setting.

> PHPUnit can perform additional checks while it executes the tests. In
>   addition to the fine-grained control over the various strict mode
>   checks (see below) you may use the --strict commandline option or set
>   strict="true" in PHPUnit's XML configuration file to enable all of
>   them.

-

> Output During Test Execution
>
> PHPUnit can be strict about output during tests. This check can be
>   enabled by using the --disallow-test-output option on the commandline
>   or by setting beStrictAboutOutputDuringTests="true" in PHPUnit's XML
>   configuration file.
>
> A test that emits output, for instance by invoking print in either the
>   test code or the tested code, will be marked as risky when this check
>   is enabled.

I believe though, that I did not activate strict mode. My command line is "/usr/bin/php /usr/bin/phpunit --colors --bootstrap /full/path/to/bootstrap.php --configuration /full/path/to/configuration.xml /full/path/to/Test.php". I also used the configuration as provided at "https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html".

```
<phpunit
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/4.3/phpunit.xsd"
   backupGlobals="true"
   backupStaticAttributes="false"
   cacheTokens="false"
   colors="false"
   convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
   convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
   convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
   forceCoversAnnotation="false"
   mapTestClassNameToCoveredClassName="false"
   printerClass="PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter"
   processIsolation="false"
   stopOnError="false"
   stopOnFailure="false"
   stopOnIncomplete="false"
   stopOnSkipped="false"
   testSuiteLoaderClass="PHPUnit_Runner_StandardTestSuiteLoader"
   timeoutForSmallTests="1"
   timeoutForMediumTests="10"
   timeoutForLargeTests="60"
   strict="false"
   verbose="false">
</phpunit>
```

I had used a shorter version of this configuration previously which provided the same result.

```
<phpunit
   beStrictAboutOutputDuringTests="false"
   strict="false"
   colors="false">
</phpunit>
```

Comment: Did you happen to solve this issue?

Comment: I did in the sense of making the reported issue go away but not in the sense of my original intention to make PHPUnit ignore the problem.

The issue was with a library that I used and I found a way to fix the problem on that end:
http://help.slimframework.com/discussions/problems/7779-output-buffers-arent-closed-when-using-app-halt

Comment: I answered this same problem here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38400305/phpunit-help-needed-about-risky-tests/40242323#40242323

Comment: I answered this same problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38400305/phpunit-help-needed-about-risky-tests/40242323#40242323

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the code available on `GitHub` **it seems** that regardless of what the documentation may say, the output buffering problem is checked and **reported always**.

So the symptoms you observe don't mean that the tests run in `strict` mode.

> [github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/4.3/src/Framework/TestCase.php#L818](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/4.3/src/Framework/TestCase.php#L818)

```php
// ...

try {
    $this->stopOutputBuffering();
} catch (PHPUnit_Framework_RiskyTestError $_e) {
    if (!isset($e)) {
        $e = $_e;
    }
}
```

> [github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/4.3/src/Framework/TestCase.php#L1938-L1946](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/4.3/src/Framework/TestCase.php#L1938-L1946)

```
private function stopOutputBuffering()
{
    if (ob_get_level() != $this->outputBufferingLevel) {
        while (ob_get_level() > 0) {
            ob_end_clean();
        }
        throw new PHPUnit_Framework_RiskyTestError(
            'Test code or tested code did not (only) close its own output buffers'
        );
    }

    // ...

    $this->outputBufferingActive = false;
    $this->outputBufferingLevel  = ob_get_level();
}
```

Placing breakpoint at the above lines in your favorite `PHPUnit` test debugger may reveal some other dependencies (like `disallowTestOutput` flag...?)

Comment: That indeed explains the problem. I had fixed the buffering issue inside the library I used then and didn't encounter a similar situation since. http://help.slimframework.com/discussions/problems/7779-output-buffers-arent-closed-when-using-app-halt

Comment: @xmojmr, Should this be considered a bug?

Comment: @Pacerier may be. I'm not too familiar with `phpunit`'s documentation. If this behavior contradicts with what the documentation says then it should be considered a bug and as such should be registered in the [issue tracker](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues) together with the other 147 opened issues

Answer (score 0):

Search your code base for error_reporting. It is possible that you might be turning on strict mode in your code. `error_reporting(E_NOTICE)` is enough to trigger the risky warning you're getting.

PHPUnit is not a special binary (I use to have this misconception), its simply PHP executing some bootstrapping mechanisms that run your code. That means your code shares the same environment that PHPUnit does--so its likely that somewhere in your code you might be setting error reporting to strict.

Comment: I have e_notice off. The problem is with the output buffering.

Answer (score 0):

From the output I believe I'm correct in assuming that you're only doing one test, so setting --stop-on-risky wouldn't really help here.

I recommend making sure you are closing your output buffering in your code itself. If you ever use something like ob_start, make sure you call ob_end_clean or ob_end_flush before your script stops executing.

As a second thought, maybe try passing the -d and -v flags when running to see if it gives you any more information.

Comment: You can [edit] all your posts and comments. Maybe you should move the comment content into your answer and then delete the comment.